# Не могу обновить виджет VK API

Tags: php, вконтакте, виджет

Доброго времени суток пользователи форума. Мне очень нужна помощь с построением JSON кода для обновления виджета VK API. Я понимаю все детали, но когда я начинаю ставить JSON код выводит ошибка:

`{"error":{"error_code":12,"error_msg":"Unable to compile code: ';' expected, 'Test' found in line 1","request_params":[{"key":"code","value":"\"return { body: { text = \"Test\", icon_id = \"lisov218\" } };\""},{"key":"type","value":"table"},{"key":"v","value":"5.52"},{"key":"method","value":"appWidgets.update"},{"key":"oauth","value":"1"}]}}`

Вот URL ссылка которую я пытаюсь отправить для обновления виджета:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/appWidgets.update?code="return { body: { text = "Test", icon_id = "lisov218" } };"&type=table&v=5.52&access_token=мой токен
```

Мне очень нужно сделать обновление виджета. Пожалуйста помогите. Искал так же тут, нашёл вопросы на которые никто не ответил. Надеюсь кто то сможет мне помочь.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь для начала с синтаксисом виджетов. В частности, там нет символов "равно".

Comment: Если не сложно, пожалуйста помогите построить правильный ответ. Мне очень нужно в скорейшем времени это выполнить.

Comment: [VK API Widgets](https://vk.com/dev/objects/appWidget?f=3.%2BTable)